# Next button is disabled while creating provided hosted app for sharepoint in visual studio

Tags: sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2012

While creating a new SharePoint Provided hosted App in VS 2012, next button on 'Specify the app for SharePoint settings' page is disabled for me. Due to which I am not able to navigate to 'Configure authentication Settings' page.[image]

1. How do I enable 'Next' button ?
2. Is there any alternative way for me to provide Certificate, Password & Issuer ID. once the project is created ?

Comment: What happens when you click the Validate button?

Comment: @Rob Windsor - It validates the url and gives 'Connection successful' message. But doesnot enable 'Next' button.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. I was using 'Office Developer Tools for VS 2012 - Preview'. When Installed 'Office Developer Tools for VS 2012 - RTM', the problem got resolved.